# Obtaining a transparent tomb. How do I do this?

Tags: html, css

To obtain the shape *(text enclosed inside the tomb like container)* I used the following design :

[image]

*(the image is given in the background)*

HTML:

```
<span class="front-page-products-title"> JUNIOR GOLFERS </span>
```

CSS:

```
.front-page-products-title {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 21em;
    height: 6em;
    border: 0.5em solid white;
    top: 0em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 4em;
    color: white;
    font-family: calibri;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    z-index: 5;

}
.front-page-products-title::before {
   position: absolute;
    border: 4em solid white;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top-right-radius: 4em;
    border-top-left-radius: 4em;
    left: 7em;
    top: -4em;
    content: '';
    z-index: 3;


}
.front-page-products-title::after {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2.5em solid white;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top-right-radius: 2.5em;
    border-top-left-radius: 2.5em;
    left: 9.5em;
    top: -2.5em;
    content: '';
    z-index: 1;

}
```

Now,I want to make the tomb transparent. Like in the following image :

[image]

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: With css3 Only? You can use background property!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will suit your needs but you can try this way:

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="grave">Some content...</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
body {
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-image: url(http://www.mooneyfarms.com/public/uploads/backgrounds/bg-body1.jpg);
}

.grave {
    border: 5px solid white;
    border-top: none;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    width: 400px;
    margin-top: 130px;
    position: relative;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, white 31%, transparent 31%, transparent 70%, white 70%);
    background-position: top left;
    background-size: 100% 5px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.grave:before {
    content: "";
    border: 5px solid white;
    border-radius: 50% 50%;
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -80px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -85px;
    clip: rect(0px,170px,85px,0px);
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/qejarm1p/

Comment: I don't need the `body,.grave:before` section. But if i leave it, i don't see the exact cut

Comment: +1 because I had never heard of the "clip" property before reading your answer.

Comment: I've edited my answer, instead of `background-attachment: fixed` i've replaced top border with `linear-gradient`. It should work in all modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

This answer probably is not the answer you are looking for, as you have tagged CSS. This answer will use javascript and HTML5. If it is not what you want, then I'd still like to keep it here for informational purposes.

I've recreated your arc but with the HTML5 canvas.

It is resizeable, you can adjust the canvas to the size you want.

The HTML:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

The javascript:

```
var canvasWidth = 300;
var canvasHeight = 205;
var lineWidth = 6;
var boxWidth = 300;
var boxHeight = 150;
var boxX = 0;
var boxY = 50;
var arcMiddleX = 150;
var arcMiddleY = 50;
var arcRadius = 50;

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.canvas.width = canvasWidth;
ctx.canvas.height = canvasHeight;
var text = "JUNIOR GOLFERS";
ctx.strokeStyle = "#FFF";
ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";
ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(arcMiddleX, arcMiddleY+lineWidth, arcRadius, Math.PI, 0);
ctx.strokeRect(boxX, boxY+lineWidth, boxWidth, boxHeight);
ctx.clearRect(boxWidth/2 - arcRadius + lineWidth/2, arcRadius + lineWidth/2, arcRadius*2 - lineWidth, 6);
ctx.font="20px calibri";
ctx.fillText(text, boxWidth/2 - ctx.measureText(text).width/2, boxHeight/2+arcRadius);
ctx.stroke();
```

The demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/713gucL1/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use SVG. I would recommend creating the shape with a program such as Adobe Illustrator (not free) or Inkscape (free and available on Linux, Windows, and Max) and then opening the file with a text editor and pasting the code into your HTML.

You can check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jLetx5nq/

Some SVG tips here: http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Code:

```
<svg width="180" height="143.15192">
  <defs id="defs4"/>
  <g transform="translate(-52.350752,-620.12034)">
    <path d="m 142.35075,620.12034 c -30.90366,0 -56.175164,24.10256 -58.041341,54.53653 l -31.958657,0 0,88.61539 179.999998,0 0,-88.61539 -31.96731,0 c -1.86618,-30.43397 -27.12902,-54.53653 -58.03269,-54.53653 z m 0,4.45673 c 29.52862,0 53.51131,24.30538 53.98269,54.47596 l 31.86347,0 0,80.30769 -171.692311,0 0,-80.30769 31.854808,0 c 0.471357,-30.1706 24.462713,-54.47596 53.991343,-54.47596 z" style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none" />
  </g>
</svg>

.background {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #3b6;
  position: relative;
}

.tomb {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 10px;
}

.text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  left: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  top: 120px;
  color: #fff;
}
```